# Set window position of an application on Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, position

I have an application which starts at position 0x0 of my desktop. I want to open it in the center of my desktop. I do not want to open it and use a move command to move it into center, instead my app should start immediately at center position.

Is there any way to do this via command prompt?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Desktop environment? Language? Do you have the sources of the program? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi Anton, I'm using windows. No I do not have the source, I have an animation creator, its output is exe, but I can not set window position for output exe and it always opens at 0x0 position.

Comment: @Sorpigal's answer may help; You may create a batch file that will launch the executable and move it's window with `cmdow`.

Comment: I published how to accomplish this in any easy way by using a generic batch script on [my blog](https://robsnotebook.com/batch-to-launch-an-application-at-desired-window-position-from-command-line/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll need an additional utility such as [cmdow.exe](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) to accomplish this. Look specifically at the `/mov` switch. You can either launch your program from `cmdow` or run it separately and then invoke `cmdow` to move/resize it as desired.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But can you give me the code for moving my app into center of desktop?

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind about this.  If you don't want to use a utility then you'll actually have to write a program that uses MoveWindow().

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't see how to use cmdow with /mov

Comment: @barlop: `cmdow` doesn't support "center", you'll have to do the math yourself and pass the appropriate values to `/mov`. Did you want the formula for centering a box inside another box?

Comment: @Sorpigal I meant just the command line to use /mov but I got it now.. doing C:\>title abcdefg<ENTER> then from another window C:\>cmdow "abcdefg" /MOV 4 6

Comment: @Sorpigal actually.. how would you do it using file handle?  I can't seem to get the hex handle for a window. winspector I can't see it in there.. nor in process explorer.

Comment: @barlop.  See my answer below

Comment: @user1167442 Thank you for that extraordinary way of pointing out to me that  `cmdow /t`  displays the handle alongside the image name, but it is good to know

Comment: if you type `cmdow /?` all will be revealed.

Answer (score 32):

Have found that [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is very good for window positioning tasks.

Here is an example script.  Call it **notepad.ahk** and then run it from the command line or double click on it.

```
Run, notepad.exe
WinWait, ahk_class Notepad
WinActivate
WinMove A,, 10, 10, A_ScreenWidth-20, A_ScreenHeight-20
```

It will start an application (notepad) and then adjust the window size so that it is centered in the window with a 10 pixel border on all sides.

Comment: Hi Fuzzy, Thanks for reply, What do you mean by "it is centered in the window with a 10 pixel border on all sides.". Is this code open my application in center of window on all computers with different resolution?

Comment: Take a look at the [WinMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) doc.  The params X and Y are given the value 10, and the width and height are given the values: screen size minus 20.  So it depends on how much space you want around the window.  If you want to maximize the window instead use the [WinMaximize](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm) function.

Comment: @FuzzyWuzzy Great solution! Using AutoHotKey, I've created a script that open four instances of [VBALink emulator](http://www.vbalink.info) (for netplay), resize all windows in order for each of them to occupy 1/4 of the desktop, and positioned each window in a different corner of my screen (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right). It worked like a charm!

Comment: Hi Fuzzy，it's a good idea. I have thought about my situation, I want to use cmd.exe run a python script, move the cmd window to special position while the python script running. Saddly I lose to find a method. If I do as you post, when the command run to `WinMove`, the script already exit. Could pls give me more advice? It seems autohotkey not support multithread. Thanks.

Comment: USE FROM TRY "Window spy" TO EASLY IDENTIFY SEARCHED ahk_class

Answer (score 27):

I just found this question while on a quest to do the same thing.

After some experimenting I came across an answer that works the way the OP would want and is simple as heck, but not very general purpose.

Create a shortcut on your desktop or elsewhere (you can use the create-shortcut helper from the right-click menu), set it to run the program "cmd.exe" and run it.  When the window opens, position it where  you want your window to be.  To save that position, bring up the properties menu and hit "Save".

Now if you want you can also set other properties like colors and I highly recommend changing the buffer to be a width of 120-240 and the height to 9999 and enable quick edit mode (why aren't these the defaults!?!)

Now you have a shortcut that will work. Make one of these for each CMD window you want opened at a different location.

Now for the trick, the windows CMD START command can run shortcuts.  You can't programmatically reposition the windows before launch, but at least it comes up where you want and you can launch it (and others) from a batch file or another program.

Using a shortcut with cmd /c you can create one shortcut that can launch ALL your links at once by using a command that looks like this:

```
cmd /c "start cmd_link1 && start cmd_link2 && start cmd_link3"
```

This will open up all your command windows to your favorite positions and individually set properties like foreground color, background color, font, administrator mode, quick-edit mode, etc... with a single click.  Now move that one "link" into your startup folder and you've got an auto-state restore with no external programs at all.

This is a pretty straight-forward solution.  It's not general purpose, but I believe it will solve the problem that most people reading this question are trying to solve.

I did this recently so I'll post my cmd file here:

```
cd /d C:\shortucts
for %%f in (*.lnk *.rdp *.url) do start %%f
exit
```

Late EDIT:  I didn't mention that if the original cmd /c command is run elevated then every one of your windows can (if elevation was selected) start elevated without individually re-prompting you.  This has been really handy as I start 3 cmd windows and 3 other apps all elevated every time I start my computer.

Comment: That's a clever solution, thanks. It seems like an acceptable hack but I think it would be a slight improvement to make a folder with several shortcuts with proper labels, like monitor0_upperleft, monitor0_upperight, and so on which could be reused as needed by simply calling them. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @jacktrader That's pretty much what I've been doing.  You can even write a batch file to execute all the scripts in a given directory on startup.

Comment: One thing I recently found, because automatic scripts with elevation was required (without saving credentials in a script).. is to set in the Local Security Policy, under Local Policies --> Security Options --> UAC (bottom set of policies) and set Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode to "Disabled" and Behavior of the elevated prompt for ... "Elevate without prompting".. will set Windows to Auto Elevate if you are admin.. such a great find. Of course there are considerations to be made. Lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nircmd` project here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Example code:

```
nircmd win move ititle "cmd.exe" 5 5 10 10
nircmd win setsize ititle "cmd.exe" 30 30 100 200
nircmd cmdwait 1000 win setsize ititle "cmd.exe" 30 30 1000 600
```

Comment: nircmd allowed me to center all active windows on a 4K monitor on a machine where I can't install PowerToys [FancyZones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones)

`nircmd win setsize alltop 960 1 1920 2160`

Answer (score 4):

This probably should be a comment under the `cmdow.exe` answer, but here is a simple batch file I wrote to allow for fairly sophisticated and simple control over all windows that you can see in the taskbar.

First step is to run `cmdow /t` to display a list of those windows.  Look at what the image name is in the column `Image`, then command line:

```
mycmdowscript.cmd imagename
```

Here are the contents of the batch file:

```
:: mycmdowscript.cmd

@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET IMAGE=%1
SET ACTION=/%2
SET REST=1
SET PARAMS=

:: GET ANY ADDITIONAL PARAMS AND STORE THEM IN A VARIABLE

FOR %%I in (%*) DO (
   IF !REST! geq 3 (
      SET PARAMS=!PARAMS! %%I
   )
   SET /A REST+=1
)

FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=1,8" %%I IN (`CMDOW /t`) DO (
     IF %IMAGE%==%%J (

     :: you now have access to the handle in %%I
     cmdow %%I %ACTION% !PARAMS!

     )
)

ENDLOCAL
@echo on

EXIT /b
```

example usage

```
:: will set notepad to 500 500

mycmdowscript.cmd notepad siz 500 500
```

You could probably rewrite this to allow for multiple actions on a single command, but I haven't tried yet.

For this to work, [cmdow.exe](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) must be located in your path.  Beware that when you download this, your AV program might yell at you.  This tool has ([*I guess*](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Tool%3AWin32%2FCmdow)) in the past been used by malware authors to manipulate windows.  It is not harmful by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Bill K.'s answer was the most elegant if you just want to start a window at startup or start from a shortcut on the desktop.

Just open the window where you want it, 
right click and choose properties.
select Layout
uncheck "let system position window"
and click OK.

Window will now open just where you want it.
You can set font and window colors at the same time on other tabs.
sweet.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to run a batch file along with a couple of tiny helper programs, a complete solution is posted here:
[How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window? - Stack Overflow (asked: May 1, 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window/)

Answer (score 2):

I too wanted to do this and came across this thread: [Positioning CMD Window](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4285). No external files to download as it creates a small bit of VBScript on the fly to do all the lifting. All you need to do is specify your X & Y coordinates in the following section: `Cscript //nologo "%~DP0pos.vbs" "%~F0" 100 50`. The .vbs script is also removed after it has been executed too so there is no need to tidy anything up.

Place this at the top of your batch file:

```
REM - Position the CMD Window Using .VBS -----------------------------------------
REM == MUST BE AT The Begining of The Batch =========
   IF "%~1" == "RestartedByVBS" Goto :Code

   REM Create the VBScript, if not exist
   IF NOT EXIST "%~DP0pos.vbs" (
      (FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr "^VBS:" ^< "%~F0"') do (
         echo(%%b
      )) > "%~DP0pos.vbs"
   )
   REM Start "" "%~DP0pos.vbs" "%~F0" 100 50
   Cscript //nologo "%~DP0pos.vbs" "%~F0" 100 50
   EXIT /B
:code
DEL /Q "%~DP0pos.vbs"
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**PLACE THE CONTENTS OF YOUR OWN BATCH FILE HERE**

And this at the bottom:

```
REM - Position the CMD Window Using .VBS -----------------------------------------
:Pos <BatchFileName> <X_Coordinate> <Y_Coordinate>

REM This Function will take three inputs: the name of the Batch file to execute
REM and the X and Y Coordinates to Position its CMD window

VBS: Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
VBS: Set objConfig = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
VBS: objConfig.SpawnInstance_
VBS: objConfig.X = WScript.Arguments(1)
VBS: objConfig.Y = WScript.Arguments(2)
VBS: Set objNewProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
VBS: intReturn = objNewProcess.Create( chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) &chr(34)& " RestartedByVBS", Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks To **FuzzyWuzzy** , set the following code ( Quick & Dirty Example for 1920x1080 screen resolution - without automatic width and height calculation or function use etc ) in **AutoHotKey** 
to achive the following : 
[image]

```
v_cmd = c:\temp\1st_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, 0, 0,1920,500

v_cmd = c:\temp\2nd_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, 0, 500,960,400

v_cmd = c:\temp\3rd_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, 960, 500,960,400
```

**SMALL EDIT**
same code with **Auto X / Y screen size calculation [ 4 monitors ]**, yet, can be used for 3 / 2 monitors as well.

```
Screen_X = %A_ScreenWidth%
Screen_Y = %A_ScreenHeight%

v_cmd = c:\temp\1st_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, 0, 0,Screen_X/2,Screen_Y/2

v_cmd = c:\temp\2nd_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, Screen_X/2, 0,Screen_X/2,Screen_Y/2

v_cmd = c:\temp\3rd_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, 0, Screen_Y/2,Screen_X/2,Screen_Y/2

v_cmd = c:\temp\4th_Monitor.ps1
Run, Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %v_cmd%
WinWait, PowerShell
Sleep, 1000
    ;A = Active window - [x,y,width,height]
WinMove A,, Screen_X/2, Screen_Y/2,Screen_X/2,Screen_Y/2
```