# How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-explorer

I have batch file that sets up the desktop environment for me when I am writing code. The file is named: `SetEnv.cmd` and it  opens 3 other windows:

1. An instance of Windows Explorer that is set to the app server's deploy directory.
2. A second instance of Windows Explorer that is set to the directory where my deployment file is written.
3. A console window to start my application server.

Here are the contents of `SetEnv.cmd`:

```
Explorer /n,c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy
Explorer /n,c:\develop\Project\Mapping\deploy
cmd /c SetupEnvCmd.cmd
```

And here are the contents of `SetupEnvCmd.cmd`:

```
cd C:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin
run
```

Every time I run this, I have to waste time rearranging and resizing the windows. I don't want to run the windows minimized, because I interact with each window many times while writing and testing code. Is there any way I can control the position and/or size of the windows that are opened from within the script?

Comment: I published how to accomplish this in any easy way by using a generic batch script on [my blog](https://robsnotebook.com/batch-to-launch-an-application-at-desired-window-position-from-command-line/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try launching your programs from VBS (Windows Script Host) script via the batch file.  If your VBS looks like this:

```
'FILENAME: SetEnv.vbs
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "Explorer /n,c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy", 4, False
Shell.Run "Explorer /n,c:\develop\Project\Mapping\deploy", 4, False
```

The `4` means to launch the window in its most recent size/position.  `False` means it won't wait to return before executing the next line of your script.  Unfortunately, this doesn't give you full control of your exact window size/positioning, but it should remember last size/positioning.

More info here: http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_Run.html

So your new SetEnv.cmd could be:

```
@echo off
REM note there's a difference between cscript and wscript
REM wscript is usually the default launcher
cscript SetEnv.vbs
cd C:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin
run
```

Comment: Ok, so I created and tried some runs. At first, it failed because it didn't like the parens being used with the Run call. I also shortened the variable name to: `Shell`, just so it would fit w/o the bottom scrollbar. But it doesn't put the windows back to their last position. It seems to be something closer to where they were, although it seem like one or the other has taken precedence for the next run. But this is definitely getting better. Thank you -

Comment: @SeanMickey, yeah, I was concerned that it wouldn't know the difference between your separate `Explorer` calls since they're both a call to the same executable.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an alternate way with nircmd util from http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
Examples:

> nircmd win move ititle "cmd.exe" 5 5 10 10
>      nircmd win setsize ititle "cmd.exe" 30 30 100 200
>      nircmd cmdwait 1000 win setsize ititle "cmd.exe" 30 30 1000 600

Here are the contents of SetEnv.cmd:

```
    Explorer /n,c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy
    nircmd wait 1000 win setsize ititle "something" x, y, width, height
    Explorer /n,c:\develop\Project\Mapping\deploy
    nircmd wait 1000 win setsize ititle "something" x, y, width, height
```

Where x,y  top left corner location and width,height are the window size
"something" is window title usually the folder name eg. "c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy"
The "wait" may need to be adjusted to give the time for the application window to initialize. So you would increase time if you have virus scanners that delay. Not so much a problem with explorer.exe or cmd.exe but something like Firefox's or java applications can vary from few seconds to several dozen seconds depending on the speed your hardware and OS tuning. You can also customize cmd.exe window or the "run" application by adding lines to "SetupEnvCmd.cmd assuming "run" is asynchronous win32 application otherwise add "start" command.

Comment: Can I just set the size of a window with nircmd and not change it's location?  It appears that "nircmd win setsize" requuires you to do both.  I want the position unchanged.

Comment: Not with `setsize`. To do that use `nircmd win move etitle "wordpad" 0 0 80 60` this would add an *EXTRA* 80 pixels width ad 60pixels height. That is assuming you know the size of the current window and it is always start the same size then you can just add incremental resize. In this example wordpad window would resize but top left hand corner would not change. Would that do?

Answer (score 19):

This problem is completely solved using a couple of helper programs and a batch file.
I have two solutions; one for single monitor computer, and another for multi-monitor computer.

### SOLUTION 1 : FOR SINGLE MONITOR COMPUTER

This demo batch file will open two Explorer windows side-by-side and centered on the screen at the primary monitor.
Read the description in the batch file.

Tools used:
1. **MonitorInfoView** by Nir Sofer *(41 KB)* ...........[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html)
2. **NirCmd** by Nir Sofer *(43 KB)* ............................[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
3. **A batch file** *(6 KB)* ............................................see below

Gather all three files into a directory.
This is the batch file, ready to run on any Windows system *(run it for an instant demo)*:

```
@echo off
REM ----- GIVE THIS CONSOLE WINDOW TITLE A UNIQUE STRING ID
title OPEN-2-EXPLORER-WINDOWS-SIDE-BY-SIDE-AND-CENTERED-ON-SCREEN-AT-THE-PRIMARY-MONITOR___20131209084355
pushd %~dp0

REM ----- HIDE THIS CONSOLE WINDOW (HOOKS THE WINDOW TITLE)
nircmd.exe win hide ititle "OPEN-2-EXPLORER-WINDOWS-SIDE-BY-SIDE-AND-CENTERED-ON-SCREEN-AT-THE-PRIMARY-MONITOR___20131209084355"

REM ********************** DESCRIPTION ************************************
REM ** This script opens one or more windows with specified screen properties
REM ** at the primary monitor (containing the taskbar). The "X/Y position" and
REM ** "W/H size" of the windows are auto-set by this script and the monitor
REM ** resolution is auto-calculated to suit.
REM ** 'MonitorInfoView.exe' is the helper tool used to capture the resolution
REM ** info of the monitor. 
REM ** 'nircmd.exe' is the tool performing all the display trickery.
REM **
REM ** To tweak this script, go to the code section named:
REM ** >>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE <<<<<
REM ***********************************************************************

REM ----- CLEAR ANY PREVIOUS JOB OUTPUTS IF THEY EXIST
if exist ~TMP.TXT type NUL > ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- OUTPUT THE PRIMARY MONITOR INFORMATION TO A TEXT FILE
MonitorInfoView.exe /hideinactivemonitors 1 /stext ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- ISOLATE THE RESOLUTION LINE, REMOVING ALL THE OTHER LINES IN THE TEXT FILE
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "Maximum Resolution"') do echo %%A>~TMP.TXT

REM ----- GET THE RESOLUTION NUMBERS, AND SET THEM AS VARIABLES
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=:X " %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT"') do set _SCREENW_=%%A& set _SCREENH_=%%B


REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [BEGIN] <<<<<<<<<<<<

REM ----- LEFT WINDOW PROPERTIES

    set _WINLEFT_=%SYSTEMDRIVE%
    set /a _WINLEFTW_=(%_SCREENW_% / 3) + 50
    set /a _WINLEFTH_=(%_SCREENH_% / 2) + 200
    set /a _WINLEFTX_=(%_SCREENW_% - %_WINLEFTW_%) / 5
    set /a _WINLEFTY_=(%_SCREENH_% - %_WINLEFTH_%) / 2

REM ----- RIGHT WINDOW PROPERTIES

    set _WINRIGHT_=%USERPROFILE%
    set /a _WINRIGHTW_=(%_SCREENW_% / 3) + 50
    set /a _WINRIGHTH_=(%_SCREENH_% / 2) + 200
    set /a _WINRIGHTX_=(%_WINLEFTX_%) + (%_WINLEFTW_%)
    set /a _WINRIGHTY_=(%_SCREENH_% - %_WINRIGHTH_%) / 2

REM ----- ADJUST THE WAIT TIME (MILLISECONDS) BETWEEN EACH WINDOW LAUNCH.
REM ----- IF TOO QUICK, THE FOLLOWING WINDOW WILL NOT SET IN THE CORRECT SCREEN POSITION.
REM ----- | FOR FAST SYSTEM: TRY 200 | NORMAL SYSTEM: TRY 400-600 | BLOATED SYSTEM: TRY 800-1200+

    set _WAITTIME_=400

REM ----- ON WINDOWS NT5 (XP, 2000), RUNNING EXPLORER WITH THE 'N' SWITCH WOULD RELIABLY GIVE
REM ----- YOU 1-PANE VIEW (HIDDEN LEFT NAV PANE). ALSO, SHOWING/HIDING OF THE LEFT NAV PANE WAS
REM ----- INSTANTLY TOGGLED BY AN ICON ON THE EXPLORER GUI TOOLBAR.
REM ----- ON WINDOWS NT6 (VISTA, 7), EXPLORER WILL NOT OBEY YOUR COMMANDS AT ALL TIMES AND IT
REM ----- IS A "PITA" TO CONTROL THE GRAPHIC USER INTERFACE. 
REM ----- THIS INPUT SECTION IS A WORKAROUND TO FORCE AN INSTANCE OF NT6 EXPLORER TO BE
REM ----- TOGGLED TO A SPECIFIED VIEW.
REM ----- |
REM ----- | INSERT ONE OF THESE VALUES INTO THE VARIABLE _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_
REM ----- | | FOR EXPLORER 2-PANE VIEW (SHOW LEFT NAVPANE):  150100000100000000000000E5010000
REM ----- | | FOR EXPLORER 1-PANE VIEW (HIDE LEFT NAVPANE):  1501000000000000000000007B020000

    set _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_=1501000000000000000000007B020000

REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [END] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


REM ----- RUN THE TASK . . .

REM ----- REGKEY 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules' DOES NOT EXIST IN NT5 OR EARLIER
REM ----- BUT TO ELIMINATE DOUBT WE WILL PERFORM A CONDITIONAL VERSION CHECK
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ver') do set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=%%A
set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=%_THIS_OS_VERSTRING_:Version =%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=." %%A in ("%_THIS_OS_VERSTRING_%") do set _THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_=%%A
if %_THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_% leq 5 goto SKIP1

set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_=PageSpaceControlSizer
if exist ~TMP.TXT type NUL > ~TMP.TXT
reg.exe query %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% > ~TMP.TXT
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 goto SKIP1
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "%_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_%"') do echo %%A>~TMP.TXT
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT"') do set _EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_=%%C
reg.exe add %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% /v %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_% /t REG_BINARY /d %_EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_% /f 2>nul >nul
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%

:SKIP1
nircmd.exe exec show "explorer.exe" /n,%_WINLEFT_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe win setsize foreground %_WINLEFTX_% %_WINLEFTY_% %_WINLEFTW_% %_WINLEFTH_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe exec show "explorer.exe" /n,%_WINRIGHT_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe win setsize foreground %_WINRIGHTX_% %_WINRIGHTY_% %_WINRIGHTW_% %_WINRIGHTH_%

REM ----- RESET SYSTEM PREF, CLEAR MEMORY, CLEANUP, QUIT . . .

find.exe /i /c "%_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_%" ~TMP.TXT
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 goto SKIP2
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
reg.exe add %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% /v %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_% /t REG_BINARY /d %_EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_% /f 2>nul >nul
:SKIP2
set _SCREENW_=
set _SCREENH_=
set _WINLEFTX_=
set _WINLEFTY_=
set _WINLEFTW_=
set _WINLEFTH_=
set _WINRIGHTX_=
set _WINRIGHTY_=
set _WINRIGHTW_=
set _WINRIGHTH_=
set _WAITTIME_=
set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=
set _THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_=
del /f /q ~TMP.TXT
popd
exit
```

### SOLUTION 2 : FOR MULTI-MONITOR COMPUTER

This demo batch file will open two Explorer windows side-by-side and centered on the screen at the other (non-primary) monitor of a two-monitor desktop. Read the description in the batch file.

*Note: For this demo, I am assuming the left monitor is Monitor-1 (the primary active monitor, containing the taskbar) and right monitor is Monitor-2 (the non-primary active monitor). If your setup is different, then tweak the script.*

Tools used:
1. **MonitorInfoView** by Nir Sofer *(41 KB)* ..............[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html)
2. **MultiMonitorTool** by Nir Sofer *(102 KB)* ...........[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
3. **NirCmd** by Nir Sofer *(43 KB)* ...............................[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
4. **A batch file** *(6 KB)* ...............................................see below

Gather all four files into a directory.
This is the batch file, ready to run on any Windows system (*run it for an instant demo*):

```
@echo off
REM ----- GIVE THIS CONSOLE WINDOW TITLE A UNIQUE STRING ID
title OPEN-2-EXPLORER-WINDOWS-SIDE-BY-SIDE-AND-CENTERED-ON-SCREEN-AT-MONITOR-2-OF-A-MULTI-MONITOR-DESKTOP___20140101024519
pushd %~dp0

REM ----- HIDE THIS CONSOLE WINDOW (HOOKS THE WINDOW TITLE)
nircmd.exe win hide ititle "OPEN-2-EXPLORER-WINDOWS-SIDE-BY-SIDE-AND-CENTERED-ON-SCREEN-AT-MONITOR-2-OF-A-MULTI-MONITOR-DESKTOP___20140101024519"

REM ********************** DESCRIPTION ************************************
REM ** This script opens one or more windows with specified screen properties
REM ** at a chosen monitor of a multi-monitor desktop. The "X/Y position" and
REM ** "W/H size" of the windows are auto-set by this script and the monitor
REM ** resolutions are auto-calculated to suit. 
REM ** 'MonitorInfoView.exe' is the helper tool used to isolate the resolution
REM ** info of the primary monitor (containing the taskbar).
REM ** 'MultiMonitorTool.exe' is the helper tool used to capture the 
REM ** resolution info of all monitors and for isolating the resolution info
REM ** of the other (non-primary) monitor.
REM ** 'nircmd.exe' is the tool performing all the display trickery.
REM **
REM ** To tweak this script, go to the code section named:
REM ** >>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE <<<<<
REM ***********************************************************************

REM ----- CLEAR ANY PREVIOUS JOB OUTPUTS IF THEY EXIST
if exist ~TMP.TXT type NUL > ~TMP.TXT
if exist ~TMP2.TXT type NUL > ~TMP2.TXT

REM ----- OUTPUT THE PRIMARY MONITOR (MONITOR-1) INFORMATION TO A TEXT FILE
MonitorInfoView.exe /hideinactivemonitors 1 /stext ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- ISOLATE THE RESOLUTION LINE OF MONITOR-1, REMOVING ALL THE OTHER LINES IN THE TEXT FILE
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "Maximum Resolution"') do echo %%A>~TMP.TXT

REM ----- GET THE RESOLUTION NUMBERS OF MONITOR-1, AND SET THEM AS VARIABLES
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=:X " %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT"') do (
set _M1_SCREENW_=%%A
set _M1_SCREENH_=%%B
)

REM ----- OUTPUT INFO OF ALL MONITORS TO TEXT FILE
MultiMonitorTool.exe /stext ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- TRY REMOVING MONITOR-1 RESOLUTION LINE (KEEPING MONITOR-2 RESOLUTION LINE)
find.exe /i /v "%_M1_SCREENW_% X %_M1_SCREENH_%" < ~TMP.TXT > ~TMP2.TXT

REM ----- TRY ISOLATING MONITOR-2 RESOLUTION LINE (REMOVING ALL THE OTHER LINES IN THE TEXT FILE)
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP2.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "Maximum Resolution"') do echo %%A>~TMP2.TXT

REM ----- CONDITIONALLY GET THE RESOLUTION NUMBERS OF MONITOR-2, AND SET THEM AS VARIABLES ...
REM ----- CASE(A): IF MONITORS HAVE SAME RESOLUTION, ASSUME NO LINES HAVE STRING "Maximum Resolution". 
REM ----- CASE(B): IF MONITORS HAVE DIFFERENT RESOLUTION, ASSUME ONE LINE HAS STRING "Maximum Resolution".
find.exe /i /c "Maximum Resolution" ~TMP2.TXT
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
set _M2_SCREENW_=%_M1_SCREENW_%&set _M2_SCREENH_=%_M1_SCREENH_%
) else (
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=:X " %%A in ('type "~TMP2.TXT"') do set _M2_SCREENW_=%%A&set _M2_SCREENH_=%%B
)    


REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [BEGIN] <<<<<<<<<<<<

REM ----- MONITOR-2 LEFT WINDOW PROPERTIES

    set _M2_WINLEFT_=%SYSTEMDRIVE%
    set /a _M2_WINLEFTW_=(%_M2_SCREENW_% / 3) + 50
    set /a _M2_WINLEFTH_=(%_M2_SCREENH_% / 2) + 200
    set /a _M2_WINLEFTX_=(%_M1_SCREENW_%) + (%_M2_SCREENW_% - %_M2_WINLEFTW_%) / 5
    set /a _M2_WINLEFTY_=(%_M2_SCREENH_% - %_M2_WINLEFTH_%) / 2

REM ----- MONITOR-2 RIGHT WINDOW PROPERTIES

    set _M2_WINRIGHT_=%USERPROFILE%
    set /a _M2_WINRIGHTW_=(%_M2_SCREENW_% / 3) + 50
    set /a _M2_WINRIGHTH_=(%_M2_SCREENH_% / 2) + 200
    set /a _M2_WINRIGHTX_=(%_M2_WINLEFTX_%) + (%_M2_WINLEFTW_%)
    set /a _M2_WINRIGHTY_=(%_M2_SCREENH_% - %_M2_WINRIGHTH_%) / 2

REM ----- ADJUST THE WAIT TIME (MILLISECONDS) BETWEEN EACH WINDOW LAUNCH.
REM ----- IF TOO QUICK, THE FOLLOWING WINDOW WILL NOT SET IN THE CORRECT SCREEN POSITION.
REM ----- | FOR FAST SYSTEM: TRY 200 | NORMAL SYSTEM: TRY 400-600 | BLOATED SYSTEM: TRY 800-1200+

    set _WAITTIME_=400

REM ----- ON WINDOWS NT5 (XP, 2000), RUNNING EXPLORER WITH THE 'N' SWITCH WOULD RELIABLY GIVE
REM ----- YOU 1-PANE VIEW (HIDDEN LEFT NAV PANE). ALSO, SHOWING/HIDING OF THE LEFT NAV PANE WAS
REM ----- INSTANTLY TOGGLED BY AN ICON ON THE EXPLORER GUI TOOLBAR.
REM ----- ON WINDOWS NT6 (VISTA, 7), EXPLORER WILL NOT OBEY YOUR COMMANDS AT ALL TIMES AND IT
REM ----- IS A "PITA" TO CONTROL THE GRAPHIC USER INTERFACE. 
REM ----- THIS INPUT SECTION IS A WORKAROUND TO FORCE AN INSTANCE OF NT6 EXPLORER TO BE
REM ----- TOGGLED TO A SPECIFIED VIEW.
REM ----- |
REM ----- | INSERT ONE OF THESE VALUES INTO THE VARIABLE _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_
REM ----- | | FOR EXPLORER 2-PANE VIEW (SHOW LEFT NAVPANE):  150100000100000000000000E5010000
REM ----- | | FOR EXPLORER 1-PANE VIEW (HIDE LEFT NAVPANE):  1501000000000000000000007B020000

    set _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_=1501000000000000000000007B020000

REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [END] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


REM ----- RUN THE TASK . . .

REM ----- REGKEY 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules' DOES NOT EXIST IN NT5 OR EARLIER
REM ----- BUT TO ELIMINATE DOUBT WE WILL PERFORM A CONDITIONAL VERSION CHECK
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ver') do set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=%%A
set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=%_THIS_OS_VERSTRING_:Version =%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=." %%A in ("%_THIS_OS_VERSTRING_%") do set _THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_=%%A
if %_THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_% leq 5 goto SKIP1

set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_=PageSpaceControlSizer
if exist ~TMP.TXT type NUL > ~TMP.TXT
reg.exe query %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% > ~TMP.TXT
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 goto SKIP1
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "%_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_%"') do echo %%A>~TMP.TXT
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT"') do set _EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_=%%C
reg.exe add %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% /v %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_% /t REG_BINARY /d %_EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_% /f 2>nul >nul
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%

:SKIP1
nircmd.exe exec show "explorer.exe" /n,%_M2_WINLEFT_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe win setsize foreground %_M2_WINLEFTX_% %_M2_WINLEFTY_% %_M2_WINLEFTW_% %_M2_WINLEFTH_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe exec show "explorer.exe" /n,%_M2_WINRIGHT_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe win setsize foreground %_M2_WINRIGHTX_% %_M2_WINRIGHTY_% %_M2_WINRIGHTW_% %_M2_WINRIGHTH_%


REM ----- RESET SYSTEM PREF, CLEAR MEMORY, CLEANUP, QUIT . . .

find.exe /i /c "%_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_%" ~TMP.TXT
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 goto SKIP2
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
nircmd.exe wait %_WAITTIME_%
reg.exe add %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_% /v %_EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_% /t REG_BINARY /d %_EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_% /f 2>nul >nul
:SKIP2
set _M1_SCREENW_=
set _M1_SCREENH_=
set _M2_SCREENW_=
set _M2_SCREENH_=
set _M2_WINLEFT_=
set _M2_WINLEFTX_=
set _M2_WINLEFTY_=
set _M2_WINLEFTW_=
set _M2_WINLEFTH_=
set _M2_WINRIGHT_=
set _M2_WINRIGHTX_=
set _M2_WINRIGHTY_=
set _M2_WINRIGHTW_=
set _M2_WINRIGHTH_=
set _WAITTIME_=
set _THIS_OS_VERSTRING_=
set _THIS_OS_MAJORVERSION_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGKEY_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_REGVAL_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_MYPREF_=
set _EXPLORER_VIEW_SYSTEMPREF_=
del /f /q ~TMP.TXT
del /f /q ~TMP2.TXT
popd
exit
```

---

### More . . .
Run a command-line program and set the position/size of its console window

**This demo batch file** will run a command-line program and set the position and size of its Command Prompt console window. The general theme of this batch is the same as the previous two solutions, but there were some unique problems and workarounds to make this work----this is a Command Prompt window hosted by 'CMD.EXE' and not a GUI window like 'EXPLORER.EXE'----Read all the comments in the batch file for more info. Read the description too.

Tools used:
1. **MonitorInfoView** by Nir Sofer *(41 KB)* ........[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html)
2. **NirCmd** by Nir Sofer *(43 KB)* .........................[homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
3. **GetPIDs** by Daniel Scheibli *(280 KB)* ..............[homepage](http://www.scheibli.com/projects/getpids/)
4. **A command-line program** .........................for this demo, I am running 'UPX.EXE' from same directory as batch ...[homepage](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)
5. **A batch file** *(6 KB)* .........................................see below

Gather all five files into a directory.
This is the batch file, ready to run on any Windows system *(run it for an instant demo)*:

What this demo batch is going to do, apart from presenting you with a custom console window, is it will run `upx.exe` with the command-line switch `--best -v -o getpids-compressed.exe getpids.exe` . We are going to compress our tool `GetPIDs` (which is 280 KB) down to 88 KB ! ..........after launching, double-click on the title bar of this console window to see an interesting phenomenon; this console window behaves like a GUI !

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
pushd %~dp0%

REM ----- ADD SOME USEFUL INFORMATION TO THIS CONSOLE WINDOW TITLE.
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('getpids.exe') do set _PROCESS_ID_=%%A
title This batch file runs a command-line program and sets the position and size of its console window        (PROCESS ID = %_PROCESS_ID_%)

REM ********************** DESCRIPTION ************************************
REM ** This script opens a command-line program console window with specified
REM ** screen properties at the primary monitor (containing the taskbar).
REM ** The "X/Y position" and "W/H size" of the console window is auto-set by
REM ** this script and the monitor resolution is auto-calculated to suit.
REM ** 'MonitorInfoView.exe' is the helper tool used to capture the resolution
REM ** info of the monitor.
REM ** 'nircmd.exe' is the tool performing all the display trickery.
REM ** 'getpids.exe' is the helper tool used to capture the Process ID of the
REM ** working batch file, thus allowing us to identify which CMD.EXE host this
REM ** console window belongs to when looking at Task Manager.
REM **
REM ** To tweak this script, go to the code section named:
REM ** >>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE <<<<<
REM ***********************************************************************

REM ----- CLEAR ANY PREVIOUS JOB OUTPUTS IF THEY EXIST
if exist ~TMP.TXT type NUL > ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- OUTPUT THE PRIMARY MONITOR INFORMATION TO A TEXT FILE
MonitorInfoView.exe /hideinactivemonitors 1 /stext ~TMP.TXT

REM ----- ISOLATE THE RESOLUTION LINE, REMOVING ALL THE OTHER LINES IN THE TEXT FILE
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT" ^|find.exe /i "Maximum Resolution"') do echo %%A>~TMP.TXT

REM ----- GET THE RESOLUTION NUMBERS, AND SET THEM AS VARIABLES
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=:X " %%A in ('type "~TMP.TXT"') do set _SCREENW_=%%A& set _SCREENH_=%%B


REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [BEGIN] <<<<<<<<<<<<

REM ----- ----------------------------------------
REM ----- |COMMAND-LINE PROGRAM TO BE RUN:  FILE NAME (WITH EXTENSION)
REM ----- |
REM ----- | |IF PROG TO BE RUN IS 'CMD.EXE' (WINDOWS COMMAND PROCESSOR)
REM ----- | |ALSO READ THE NEXT COMMENTS ABOUT SETTING SWITCHES

    set _MYPROGRAM_=upx.exe

REM ----- ----------------------------------------   
REM ----- |COMMAND-LINE PROGRAM TO BE RUN:  SWITCHES (TO BE PASSED TO THE PROGRAM)
REM ----- |
REM ----- | |YOU CAN LEAVE THIS VARIABLE WITH A BLANK VALUE IF RUNNING THE PROG WITHOUT ANY PARAMETERS
REM ----- | | 
REM ----- | | |IF THE VALUE CONTAINS THE CHARS  '|'  OR  '<'  OR  '>'  THIS BATCH WILL FAIL TO RUN !!!
REM ----- | | |
REM ----- | | | |YOU CAN APPEND EXTRA TEXT TO THE END OF THE COMMAND BY USING THE AMPERSAND CHARACTER '&'
REM ----- | | | | EXAMPLES:
REM ----- | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=dir "%systemroot%\system32" /a/o/s/4 & this text will be ignored; useful for adding some inline comments.
REM ----- | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=dir "%systemroot%\system32" /a/o/s/4         & this works too, and the extra blank spaces will also be ignored.
REM ----- | | | | 
REM ----- | | | | |IF PROG TO BE RUN IS 'CMD.EXE' (WINDOWS COMMAND PROCESSOR), PATH ARGUMENTS MUST POINT TO A SPECIFIC LOCATION
REM ----- | | | | |AND BE ABSOLUTE OR INCLUDE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, AND ALWAYS ENCLOSE PATHS IN QUOTES.
REM ----- | | | | | EXAMPLES:
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=type "C:\Folder With Spaces\File.txt"
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=type "C:\FolderWithoutSpaces\File.txt"
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=type "%SYSTEMROOT%\..\Folder With Spaces\File.txt"
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=type %0                                       <<<<<<<this batch file (quotes are optional; the only exception to the rule)
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=type "%~dp0%\..\File.txt"                     <<<<<<<goes back one Dir from this batch file
REM ----- | | | | | set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=dir "%systemroot%\system32" /a/o/s/4          <<<<<<<displays directory listing of the System folder. NOTE: 'dir' by itself and
REM ----- | | | | |                                                                                without a specific path argument will resolve to the folder of this batch file.

    set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=--best -v -o getpids-compressed.exe getpids.exe      &// original is 280 KB, will compress down to 88 KB

REM ----- ----------------------------------------
REM ----- |COMMAND-LINE PROGRAM TO BE RUN:  DIRECTORY PATH (OF THE PROGRAM)
REM ----- | 
REM ----- | |YOU CAN LEAVE THIS VARIABLE WITH A BLANK VALUE IF THE PROG IS AT SAME LOCATION AS BATCH
REM ----- | |THIS VARIABLE WILL BE IGNORED IF THE PROG IS 'CMD.EXE'
REM ----- | | 
REM ----- | | EXAMPLES:
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=.\                               <<<<<<<program and batch in same directory
REM ----- | |                                                                  dot backslash *OR* dot (trailing backslash is optional).
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%dp0%                            <<<<<<<program and batch in same directory
REM ----- | |                                                                  same locatiion as previous but using environment variable.
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=..\                              <<<<<<<program is back one directory from batch
REM ----- | |                                                                  dot dot backslash *OR* dot dot (trailing backslash is optional).
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%dp0%\..                         <<<<<<<program is back one directory from batch
REM ----- | |                                                                  same as location as previous but using environment variable.
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%SYSTEMROOT%\..\My Utilities     <<<<<<<program is back one directory from the Windows folder
REM ----- | |                                                                  and then forwards into the folder 'My Utilities'
REM ----- | | set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=C:\My Utilities\                 <<<<<<<enclosing quotes are optional; trailing backslash is optional
REM ----- | |                                                                  same location as previous

    set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=

REM ----- ----------------------------------------
REM ----- |SET THE WANTED DIMENSIONS OF THIS CONSOLE WINDOW

    set /a _WINW_=(%_SCREENW_% / 2) + 250
    set /a _WINH_=(%_SCREENH_% / 2) + 150
    set /a _WINX_=(%_SCREENW_% - %_WINW_%) / 2
    set /a _WINY_=(%_SCREENH_% - %_WINH_%) / 2

REM ----- ----------------------------------------
REM ----- |STYLE THIS CONSOLE WINDOW   !!!IMPORTANT!!!
REM ----- |
REM ----- | |IF WE DO NOT USE THE 'MODE' COMMAND HERE ALONG WITH ITS 'COLS/LINES' VALUES THEN
REM ----- | |THE POSITIONING/SIZING OF THIS WINDOW BY 'NIRCMD.EXE' FURTHER DOWN WILL NOT WORK !!!
REM ----- | |
REM ----- | | |SOME COMMANDS WILL OUTPUT A LOT OF LINES AND AND THE CONSOLE DISPLAY WILL BE TRUNCATED
REM ----- | | |RUN THIS FOR AN EXAMPLE=====>   cmd.exe dir "%systemroot%\system32" /a/o/s/4   <=====
REM ----- | | |TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM, SET THE 'LINES' VALUE OF 'MODE' TO A VERY HIGH NUMBER
REM ----- | | |THE MAXIMUM NUMBER IS 32000 (ON MY SYSTEM); 'MODE' WILL BE IGNORED IF THE NUMBER IS HIGHER !!!  

    color 0A
    mode.com con:cols=%_SCREENW_% lines=10000

REM ----- ----------------------------------------
REM ----- |DELETE THE TEMP TEXT FILE MADE BY 'MonitorInfoView.exe'
REM ----- |COMMENT OUT THE LINE IF YOU DON'T CARE ABOUT DELETING IT

    del /f /q ~TMP.TXT 2>nul >nul

REM >>>>>>>>>> USER INPUT/PREFERENCES ARE ALL SET HERE [END] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
REM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


REM ----- RUN THE TASK . . .
nircmd.exe win setsize foreground %_WINX_% %_WINY_% %_WINW_% %_WINH_%
popd

if not defined _MYPROGRAMDIR_ set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%~dp0
if "!_MYPROGRAMDIR_!" == "." set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%~dp0
if "!_MYPROGRAMDIR_!" == ".\" set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%~dp0
pushd %_MYPROGRAMDIR_%
if not exist %_MYPROGRAMDIR_% goto _SKIP_
set _CONVERT_PATH_="%CD%"
set _CONVERT_PATH_=%_CONVERT_PATH_:"=%
set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=%_CONVERT_PATH_%
:_SKIP_
popd

echo ===============================================================================
echo PROGRAM ..............: !_MYPROGRAM_!
if "!_MYPROGRAM_!"=="cmd.exe" (echo PROGRAM DIR ..........: %SYSTEMROOT%\system32) else (echo PROGRAM DIR ..........: !_MYPROGRAMDIR_!)
echo PROGRAM SWITCHES .....: !_MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_!
echo ===============================================================================

if "!_MYPROGRAM_!"=="cmd.exe" (goto _PROGRAM_IS_CMD_) else (goto _PROGRAM_IS_OTHER_)

:_PROGRAM_IS_CMD_
cd /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32"
!_MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_!
echo. & echo. & echo.
goto _END_

:_PROGRAM_IS_OTHER_ 
cd /d "!_MYPROGRAMDIR_!"
if "%CD%\!_MYPROGRAM_!" == "%CD%\" goto _ERRORMESSAGE_
if not exist "%CD%\!_MYPROGRAM_!" goto _ERRORMESSAGE_
"!_MYPROGRAMDIR_!\!_MYPROGRAM_!" !_MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_!
echo. & echo. & echo.
goto _END_

:_ERRORMESSAGE_
cls
color 4F
echo ===============================================================================
echo PROGRAM ..............: !_MYPROGRAM_!
echo PROGRAM DIR ..........: !_MYPROGRAMDIR_!
echo PROGRAM SWITCHES .....: !_MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_!
echo ===============================================================================
echo                        ^^!^^!^^!  E R R O R  ^^!^^!^^!
echo.
echo The program has failed to run; the path set by the above values does not exist.
echo Please exit this window and check the values you have set in this batch file.
echo.
echo This batch file is located here:
echo %0
echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo.

:_END_

REM ----- CLEAR VARIABLE VALUES FROM MEMORY . . .
set _PROCESS_ID_=
set _SCREENW_=
set _SCREENH_=
set _MYPROGRAM_=
set _MYPROGRAMSWITCHES_=
set _MYPROGRAMDIR_=
set _WINW_=
set _WINH_=
set _WINX_=
set _WINY_=
set _CONVERT_PATH_=

REM ----- STOP THIS CONSOLE WINDOW FROM CLOSING   !!!IMPORTANT!!! . . .
REM ----- SEE <http://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution>
cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 7):

Following method can be useful for new users who doesn't want to download third-party tools and have modern *PowerShell* (PS).

Script was based on [post](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post7895914.html) by Garry Galler. All folders from question, but you can replace with yours.

Create file `SetPositionAndSizeForExplorerWindow.ps1` with PS script:

```
# PowerShell script for opening Explorer windows and changing its position and size

# add .NET type
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Win32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string ClassName, IntPtr  TitleApp);
  }
  public struct RECT
  {
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
  }
"@

# set variable for RECT object
$rcWindow = New-Object RECT

#----- REPLACE WITH YOUR PATHs from HERE---------

# open first folder in separate Explorer process
explorer.exe "c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy"

# magic sleep =) to wait starting explorer on slow machines
sleep -Milliseconds 1500

$h1 = (Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -match "deploy"}).MainWindowHandle

# check if there is a window with this Title, if NO - return
if ($h1 -eq [IntPtr]::Zero) {return "Cannot find window with this Title"}

# bind RECT object with our window
[void][Win32]::GetWindowRect($h1,[ref]$rcWindow)
# set new position and size for window 
[void][Win32]::MoveWindow($h1, 10, 10, 700, 345, $true)

# remember PID to exclude it for next window with the same name
$duplicate = (Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -match "deploy"}).Id

# open second folder in separate Explorer process
explorer.exe "c:\develop\Project\Mapping\deploy"
sleep -Milliseconds 1500
$h1 = (Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -match "deploy" -and $_.Id -ne $duplicate}).MainWindowHandle
if ($h1 -eq [IntPtr]::Zero) {return "Cannot find window with this Title"}
[void][Win32]::GetWindowRect($h1,[ref]$rcWindow)
[void][Win32]::MoveWindow($h1, 400, 20, 700, 335, $true)

# open cmd window with title SetupEnvCmd.cmd
cmd /c "start C:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin\SetupEnvCmd.cmd"
sleep -Milliseconds 1500
# cmd.exe process has no own title, that's why we get PID searching by CommandLine process property
$process = "cmd.exe"
$cmdPID = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | where {$_.CommandLine -match "SetupEnvCmd"} | select ProcessId
$h1 = (Get-Process | where {$_.Id -eq $cmdPID.ProcessId}).MainWindowHandle
if ($h1 -eq [IntPtr]::Zero) {return "Cannot find window with this Title"}
[void][Win32]::GetWindowRect($h1,[ref]$rcWindow)
[void][Win32]::MoveWindow($h1, 200, 400, 800, 400, $true)
```

Move it to `C:\develop folder`.
Create `OpenDevelopEnv.bat` file to run this .ps1 script (in order not to delve into security policy of PS):

```
Powershell -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\develop\SetPositionAndSizeForExplorerWindow.ps1"
```

Run `OpenDevelopEnv.bat`

**For multi-display configuration** you can use negative coordinates, for instance: for opening window on left display (relative to the main) you can write:

```
[void][Win32]::MoveWindow($h1, -600, 400, 800, 400, $true)
```

**Disadvantages:**

- PowerShell must be installed;
- required windows must be closed;
- folders starts in separate
  processes;
- using of sleep time for correct work on slow machines.

*Tested on*: Windows 10 Pro 1803 x64/x86 with PSVersion 5.1 (administrator and regular users)

Comment: Thank you for providing this example. I have tried this as well as another PowerShell example found online. In both cases, I am unable to obtain the window handle by the method $h1 = (Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -match "deploy"}).MainWindowHandle  This always returns a null string "".  I am using Windows 10, on a 64-bit machine. What might be the problem here? Is there a better way to obtain the handle?

Comment: @Raisintoe, it's hard to understand where your problem is, without your environment and code reproducing. Check your code carefully (debug each line after .NET type definition at the beginning), check that window containing "deploy" string exists manually (in Windows Task Manager), check that it can be activated (not modal, or something else). At least window handle should be 'handle type' `$h1 -eq [IntPtr]::Zero` not an empty string (as you get).

Comment: Okay, I am now getting incompatible types: cannot convert type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IntPtr". This is referring to the MoveWindow function, where it takes the paramter$h1. It appears that Get-Process returns the type System.Object[], while MoveWindow expects System.IntPtr as the hWnd parameter.

Comment: @Raisintoe I've just run this script (except the last step with opening CMD window). Two 'deploy' Win Explorer windows  are opened and moved to new locations. Script still works with latest Powershell `7.2.5` with latest Windows 10 Updates x64 Pro. My code still valid (despite the warnings about `where` and `sleep` aliases in it). Provide your code, environment, and (maybe) we will help you. Or better, inspect your code yourself carefully and change line by line from this example. **May the Force be with you** :)

Comment: @Raisintoe ah ha ha. After writing comment above. I deleted folders from example and got your errors. OKEY, try this: ALL FOLDERS MUST BE CREATED BEFORE RUNNING SCRIPT (exist). I thought you'd guess to create them (or read comment `REPLACE WITH YOUR PATHs from HERE`).

Comment: @Raisintoe And *ONE MORE THING* (I think this is your problem). Explorer process may be "stuck" in Task Manager (no window on display and taskbar, BUT explorer process with 'deploy' name still running). You MUST kill this process manually in Task Manager (I wrote about this in the first comment) or reboot your PC.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [**StartX**](http://www.naughter.com/startx.html). I haven't used it, but it looks like you can use it to launch an application with a specific position and size.

> StartX, a very simple utility to allow you to call the CreateProcess API from the command line.

Some of its commandline parameters:

```
StartX ["title"] [/Dpath] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/Px,y] [/Scx1,cy1]
```

> **x,y:**  Specifies the x and y offset, in pixels, of the upper left corner of a window if a new window is created. The offset is from the upper left corner of the screen.
>
> **cx1, cy2:**   Specifies the width and height, in pixels, of the window if a new window is created.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, I'd suggest using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which would easily handle this (better than Powershell and Batch, in my opinion).

As a simple sample, to launch the two instances of Explorer, resize (and move) them, then do the same with the cmd window you might do something like this:

```
Run Explorer /n,c:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy
Run Explorer /n,c:\develop\Project\Mapping\deploy
WinMove, deploy, server\default, 0, 0, 200, 200
WinMove, deploy, Project\Mapping, 200, 0, 200, 200
Run cmd /c SetupEnvCmd.cmd
WinMove, C:\develop\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin, 0, 200
```

[WinMove Help Doc](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)