# Launch two Explorer windows side-by-side

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Is there a way to launch two Explorer windows side-by-side (vertically tiled) with a Batch script?

If not, how might I do this with VBS?

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried so far as code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the VBS script above by **Hackoo** to do exactly what the OP wants...

The comments in the script explain exactly what it will do.
If the two windows don't set into correct position, increase the 'Sleep' time and try again.
If you want a horizontal split, use 'objShell.TileHorizontally'.

```
Option Explicit
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Launches two Explorer windows side-by-side filling the screen dimensions.
''' Minimizes all current open windows before launch; if this is not done,
''' the current open windows will also be resized along with our two windows.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim Calc,AppData,objShell
Calc = "%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
AppData = "%AppData%"
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")

objShell.MinimizeAll
Call Explore(Calc)
WScript.Sleep 800
Call Explore(AppData)
WScript.Sleep 800
objShell.TileVertically
Set objShell = nothing

'*****************************************************
Function Explore(Path)
    Dim ws
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    Explore = ws.run("Explorer /n,/select,"& Path &"")
End Function
'*****************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be in the same category as your question. :) 
[How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window)

Unfortunately it seems that its not possible without any external third part software in batch. Probably easier in VBS - if so the answer should be in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Calc,AppData
Calc = "%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
AppData = "%AppData%"
Call Explore(Calc)
Call Explore(AppData)
'*****************************************************
Function Explore(Path)
    Dim ws
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    Explore = ws.run("Explorer /n,/select,"& Path &"")
End Function
'*****************************************************
```