# How to open 2 apps into split screen?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm trying to open 2 applications with a VBScript file and make them split screen. I was following [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296043/launch-two-explorer-windows-side-by-side) below but it's only getting me to the file location and not actually launching it.

```
Option Explicit
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Launches two Explorer windows side-by-side filling the screen dimensions.
''' Minimizes all current open windows before launch; if this is not done,
''' the current open windows will also be resized along with our two windows.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim Calc,objShell
Calc = "%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

objShell.MinimizeAll
Call Explore(Calc)
WScript.Sleep 800
Call Explore(Calc)
WScript.Sleep 800
objShell.TileVertically
Set objShell = Nothing

'*****************************************************
Function Explore(Path)
  Dim ws
  Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Explore = ws.run("Explorer /n,/select,"& Path &"")
End Function
'*****************************************************
```

Comment: Does it show any error message?

Comment: no errors, it just opens 2 windows explorers side by side. I'm trying to get calc.exe or any .exe to open in split screen.

Answer (score 0):

The script does exactly what you tell it to do: open two Explorer windows with the locations of the two programs. That is what `explorer /n,/select,...` does. If you want to run the programs instead of opening their location you need to, well, actually run the programs:

```
ws.run """" & Path & """"
```

The double quotes are there to avoid issues with spaces in a path.

As a side note: it's pointless to have a function return something when you're never using that return value anyway. Just make it a `Sub` instead.