# ms-edge launched via powershell - is there a way to have it launch in a particular DESKTOP? (task view button on Windows 10)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I am launching an MS Edge window with a particular URL via Powershell: (example)

```
Start-Process msedge.exe https:\\google.com
Start-Process msedge.exe https:\\blah.com
Start-Process msedge.exe https:\\foo.com
```

... is there a way from Powershell to make it open in a particular DESKTOP?

I can create multiple desktops using the "task view" button.   For instance, I may want the first instance of Edge in the script to launch on desktop one.   The second on desktop two, and the third on desktop three.

It would also be interesting to know if I can (through powershell) create the desktops if they don't already exist (by default there is only one).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting programs on multiple desktops using powershell in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491872/starting-programs-on-multiple-desktops-using-powershell-in-windows-10)

Comment: Abraham:  I'm currently testing Josh Gallagher's powershell specific solution from that thread.  I will let you know how it turns out but it may be tomorrow.

Comment: I think the thread in the above comment can answer your question. I test that `Install-Module VirtualDesktop` and `Get-Desktop 1 | Switch-Desktop` can switch to specific desktop. Then the browser will be launched in that desktop.