# Java Virtual Machine Error When Trying To Run an Application From Java

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, processbuilder

I am trying to run an .exe from a java application, but I am getting this error message:

Java Virtual Machine Launcher(title)
   A Java Exception has occurred.

I have tried:

```
try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rt.exec("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe");
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
            InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
} catch (Exception exc) {}
```

And:

```
try {
            Process process = new         ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe").start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Both of them work when I try to run something else like uTorrent, but it fails when I try to run the .exe that I have to.

Also, this .exe is in a folder and if I try to run this .exe alone (out of it's folder) it returns the same error message.

I don't think the code above is wrong, but it's missing something to be able to run my .exe.

New CODE:

```
try
        {

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe");                
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<ERROR>");
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</ERROR>");
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

New Output:

```
<ERROR>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **org/lwjgl/LWJGLException**
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
</ERROR>
Process exitValue: 0
```

Comment: Could you show the full error message and call stack.

Comment: Well, that is the full error message. Where in my code should I call Stack? Thank you for your fast reply. @Tarik

Comment: HAHA, that was gold! Sorry for being unprofessional, but this is funny right here.

Comment: Herbert, the call stack is the chain of Method calls. The stack trace shows the chain of method calls that lead to the error and includes the offending line. See   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(). Note that most IDE's print the stack trace upon unhandled errors.

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: Alright, I did what you guys told me to. Now we can see that the Exception is about LWJGL (which is a java library for games). The application I am trying to run is a game based on Java, just like Minecraft. @AndrewThompson

Comment: So.. `MyExe.exe` is actually a Java app. that is supposed to access the LWJGL API?  Does your `exe` work when you double click it, or (better, for output) launch it from the command line?

Comment: @Herbert yes you need to debug the exe first; your calling app isn't the main problem here (although you'll want a separate thread for your stream reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting you:

> Also, this .exe is in a folder and if I try to run this .exe alone
>   (out of it's folder) it returns the same error message.

Most likely you are forgetting to set appropriate directory. Use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()`, and make a call to `ProcessBuilder.directory(File)` method before `ProcessBuilder.start()`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-from-java-from-file-location) for more information.

Comment: Bingo! Should I post the final result? Only one more question, just for curiosity... is it possible to run the applicative in windows mode? Thank you! @fernacolo

Comment: What do you mean by "windows mode"? Without a console window?

Comment: I mean not on fullscreen and with a window size defined by parameters. Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Your English is good, don't worry. There's no way to do what you want in Java SE. You need a native Java library that wraps the [CreateProcess API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), or an external utility. Take a look a [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line).

Comment: By the way, you should consider following StackExchange ethics and mark this answer as a solution. :)

Comment: Alright. Thank you and everyone else for helping. I will take a look at the link you sent me.