# Adjust window position with batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to adjust the window position when a window is opened when launching from a .bat file?

I have two programs I want to open and I have a batch file that does it, but they both end up on top of each other.

I know you can start programs minimized or maximized, but I'd like to know if there is a way I can make one take up the left half and the other take up the right half of the monitor?

Comment: Alternatively to the suggestions in that thread if the OP's OS has powershell, he may be able to encapsulate some wasp.dll Set-WindowPoistion commands inside his batch file.   http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

There is no native support to move a window from a batch file.  There are utilities that can do this for you.

Here is another thread that discusses the same topic.

[Set The Window Position of an application via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line)