# Windows: Open program in specific screen location

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

At work, I have a set of batch files and scripts which I use to automate all the programs I need to open in the morning (and others to close them all down at night) in order to save time and effort. The problem is, the windows all open in whatever location they so choose, since most of the information is cleared out overnight on the Virtual Desktop.

I have seen people talking of desktop managers and additional programs that make such tasks easier, but due to the restrictions at play, I do not have the ability to install programs like that. I also do not have access to edit registry files, and I can never be sure if the registry files will stay the same or be wiped and reimaged at night. So re-opening at the stored previous location seems to be out. This means that `AutoHotKey` , `cmdow` , and most `.exe` program options are out of the running.

Essentially what I am looking for is a way to reposition open windows, or open windows in a specific position, using either batch files or vbs. Preferably with a location relative to the screen rather than other windows, as I use multiple monitors.

I'm open to using powershell or potentially other options, but those would likely fall outside my experience. It seems like what I'm asking is either nonexistent or impossible, but I'm hoping maybe someone has an idea. I don't mind complicated code, but I have no idea where to begin on this one guys, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set The Window Position of an application via command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

It look like someone as already answer that kind of question here :

[Other post on set many programs window size and position](https://superuser.com/questions/769575/set-many-programs-window-size-position)

You can also use C# and map powershell on it using cmdlet in powershell and c# as backend. Here is an exemple in c# and just google how to make cmdlet in powershell.

[Example in c#](http://rlbisbe.net/2013/11/19/moving-windows-programatically-with-windows-api-the-path-to-winresize/)

Answer (score 0):

Batch files can't do this. A VBScript can sort of do this using Windows Script Host Object Model.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle: See below], [bWaitOnReturn: TRUE/FALSE])
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**intWindowStyle values:**

0  -  Hides the window and activates another window.
1  -  Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when displaying the window for the first time.
2  -  Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window.
3 - Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window.
4 - Displays a window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.
5 - Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position.
6 - Minimizes the specified window and activates the next top-level window in the Z order.
7 - Displays the window as a minimized window. The active window remains active.
8 - Displays the window in its current state. The active window remains active.
9 - Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
10 - Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.

Not sure about PowerShell. :/

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the way most programs store 'most recent size and position' is dependent on data stored in locations that may be wiped at any time. I was thinking powershell or some other sort of scripting might have better options but I also hoped I'd missed something in the ones I know better.