# How to open batch file console window in a specific location of screen

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I want to open my batch file's console window in a specific location on the screen. I have searched in Google, but I did not find a solution for this. I need four small console windows, one in each corner of the screen.

Comment: Maybe this [Set The Window Position of an application via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line)

Comment: I cant find the solution, Please any help me, regarding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

if /i "%~1" == "/4way" (
    console4way "%~f0" %*
    exit /b
)

echo Running %*
```

console4way

```
#pragma compile(Out, console4way.exe)

Global $aPid[4]

; Run ComSpec (usually set as CMD) with arguments for the 1st instance.
$aPid[0] = Run('"' & @ComSpec & '" /k ' & StringReplace($CMDLINERAW, '/4way', '', 1))

For $i1 = 1 To 3
    $aPid[$i1] = Run('"' & @ComSpec & '"')
Next

; Give time for all windows to display.
Sleep(500)

; Get list of all console class windows.
$aWinList = WinList('[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]')

For $i1 = 1 To UBound($aWinList) -1
    ; Get current window handle from the list.
    $hWindow = $aWinList[$i1][1]

    ; Get position and sizes of current window.
    $aPos = WinGetPos($hWindow)

    ; Move windows if process id matches.
    Switch WinGetProcess($hWindow)
        Case $aPid[0]
            WinMove($hWindow, '', 0, 0)
        Case $aPid[1]
            WinMove($hWindow, '', @DesktopWidth - $aPos[2], 0)
        Case $aPid[2]
            WinMove($hWindow, '', 0, @DesktopHeight - $aPos[3])
        Case $aPid[3]
            WinMove($hWindow, '', @DesktopWidth - $aPos[2], @DesktopHeight - $aPos[3])
    EndSwitch
Next
```

batch-file alone seems incapable to do this task without
external assistance.

You may need something that can handle 4 windows by their
handles and move them to position.
The 4 windows may need to be recognized by the Process ID
to ensure the correct windows are handled.

The code of `console4way` is AutoIt3.

The batch file, if executed with `/4way` as 1st argument,
will execute console4way.exe. 4 console processes will
execute and a short sleep will happen to allow the windows
to appear.
`WinList` will get the console windows by class.
Each window handle is used to get position, size and process ID.
As each process ID is matched, the current window is moved to
a position in the corner of the Desktop as specified.

The width and height of the windows is not specified.
`WinMove` allows another 2 parameters for width and height.
`$aPos[2]` and `$aPos[3]` are the width and height of the
current console window.

Execute the batch file with the argument of `/4way` to
initiate the batch file to execute `console4way`,
else it will execute without `console4way`.
You can add further arguments after the `/4way` argument
if you want to pass arguments to the batch file to use.

Compile `console4way.au3` to executable to match the bitness of the OS
so that it executes ComSpec of the same environment.

---

**About console4way**

`console4way` is the command to execute `console4way.exe`.
You can have your au3 script named `console4way.au3`
(which is a text file containing the code above).
Use the au3 script file to compile `console4way.exe`
with instructions provided.

Once compiled, you only need the batch file and
`console4way.exe` to be in the same path and execute
the batch file to test.
You can store the au3 script and use it later
if you want to compile again or update the code.

---

**Instructions to compile `console4way.au3`**:

with installer:

1. Download [AutoIt3](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and install.
2. Rightclick on `console4way.au3` and select
   `Compile Script (x64)` for 64 bit OS, else
   `Compile Script (x86)` for 32 bit OS.
3. In same directory, you should now have a `console4way.exe`.

or with zip:

1. Download [AutoIt3](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and unzip.
2. Navigate to `install\Aut2Exe` and execute `Aut2Exe.exe`.
   If on a 64 bit OS, you can execute `Aut2Exe_x64.exe` instead.
   Either will work the same to compile to x86 or to x64 executable.
3. *Source* input is the path to `console4way.au3`.
4. Leave *Destination* input empty so it compile to
   same directory as the script.
   *.exe* radio button should be selected.
5. Check *Compile for System x64* checkbox for 64bit compile.
6. Click <kbd>Convert</kbd> button to compile.
7. In same directory, you should now have a `console4way.exe`.

`console4way.exe` will be a self contained executable that can
be executed on an OS without AutoIt installed.

**Additional**:

Review help page about [Compiling](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm) Scripts with Aut2Exe.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for your answer, But still I am bit confuse to implementing the code, could you explain how to implement this code, I mean, console4way is a seperate file, what is console4way.exe, Please tell me about how to implement your code.

Comment: I added an *About console4way* and *Instructions to compile* section to address your concerns mentioned in your comment.