# How do you find the location and window size of a window (using python)?

Tags: python

If I have an application name+PID, how do I find the location and window size of it using python?

Comment: Are you using the console or a GUI if GUI which one?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way of doing this directly with python, but you could use python to execute cmd commands. Take a look:

> CMD commands on python:
>   [How to execute a command prompt command from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python)
>
> Window parameters from cmd:
>   [Set The Window Position of an application via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line)